# binary tree traversal

Tags: java, binary-tree

i have made an binary tree, and im trying to make an postorder traversal. I have already made an preorder traversal - which i though was what i needed. But after googling traversal i found out that it was postorder i need. 
My thoughts are on the traversal that first the left comes out, then the right and then the root(it is postorder right? :) ).
I have tried to implement it, but it looks a bit odd the out come

```
public static <E> String postorder(BinaryTree<E> t, Position<E> v){
    String tree = "";
    if(t.hasLeft(v)){
        tree += postorder(t, t.left(v));
    }
    tree += v.element()  +", ";
    if(t.hasRight(v)){
        tree += postorder(t, t.right(v));
    }
    return tree;
}
```

My tree is:

```
            45
           /   \
          22    77
         /  \      \
        11   30     90
         \    /     /
         15  25    88
```

My result should be after my knowledge
15,11,25,30,22,88,90,77,45
But it is
11,15,22,25,30,45,77,88,90

Can anyone see what im doing wrong - i have tried so many things. Nothing works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling `preorder` from within the implementation of `postorder`.

---

Update:  now it looks like you're doing an **in-order** traversal but *calling* it **postorder**.

Move this line:

```
tree += v.element()  +", ";
```

to the end (right before returning).

Comment: it is now updated.. Can you see the error? it comes out inorder instead of postorder

Answer (score 0):

```
void preOrder(BSTNode *root){
    while(root != NULL){
       cout<<root->data<<endl;
       preOrder(root->left);
       preOrder(root->right);
    }
}

void postOrder(BSTNode *root){
    while(root != NULL){
       preOrder(root->left);
       preOrder(root->right);
       cout<<root->data<<endl;
    }
}

 void inOrder(BSTNode *root){
    while(root != NULL){
       preOrder(root->left);
       cout<<root->data<<endl;
       preOrder(root->right);
    }
}
```